# Map Wacom Intuos to one monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr, wacom

I have some trouble mapping my Wacom Tablet to one of my three displays.

I tried the following `xsetwacom -v set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad" MapToOutput DP1-2`. I got this output:

```
... Display is '(null)'.
... 'set' requested for 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad'.
... Checking device 'Virtual core pointer' (2).
... Checking device 'Virtual core keyboard' (3).
... Checking device 'Virtual core XTEST pointer' (4).
... Checking device 'Virtual core XTEST keyboard' (5).
... Checking device 'Power Button' (6).
... Checking device 'Video Bus' (7).
... Checking device 'Power Button' (8).
... Checking device 'Sleep Button' (9).
... Checking device 'PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse' (10).
... Checking device 'Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard' (11).
... Checking device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' (12).
... Checking device 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse' (13).
... Checking device 'DELL Wireless hotkeys' (14).
... Checking device 'Dell WMI hotkeys' (15).
... Checking device 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus' (16).
... Checking device 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad' (17).
... Device 'Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad' (17) found.
... Found output 'eDP1' (connected)
... CRTC (5120x0) 1920x1080
... Found output 'DP1' (disconnnected)
... Found output 'DP1-1' (connected)
... CRTC (0x0) 2560x1440
... Setting CRTC DP1-1
... Remapping to output area 2560x1440 @ 0,0.
... Transformation matrix:
...     [ 0.363636 0.000000 0.000000 ]
...     [ 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 ]
...     [ 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 ]
```

I think this seems to work, am I right?

But nothing happens at all, the Intous Pad is still mapped to all three displays..

Answer (score 2):

You want to map the "Pen Stylus" (eg "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen Stylus") not the "Pad pad":

```
$ xsetwacom --list
Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus         id: 12  type: STYLUS    <--- This one
Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad            id: 13  type: PAD
```

For others who may find this question you get the name of your monitor (DP1-2 above) from the 'xrandr' command.

More info: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xsetwacom

Comment: xrandr --query gives you the list of display devices , from where you can pick the name of the display, in my case it was HDMI-1